# ESP32 or ESP8266 220v button as input

Tags: esp8266, esp32

As per title I'm, looking a way to detect the press of a button powered at 220v ac through a gpio pin of the ESP32.

The simplest solution found seems to be an octocoupler, but are there devices that support such a high voltage difference? What could be a connection scheme?

Comment: why don't you do some research? ... you are not the first to solve this

Comment: `what could be a connection scheme?` ... connection to what? ... your post has no information

Comment: How is a “button powered at 220V”? A button does not use any power (or an extremely small amount). A button just opens or closes a circuit, which in the simplest case would be between your local reference voltage (usually 3.3V or 5V) or ground and a GPIO pin (details vary depending on the type of button). If there’s 220V somewhere around, there’s more than just a button… please provide a schematic of the circuit which includes this button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommending just getting a small normally open (NO) relay with 230V AC coil and then run your ESP32 Vcc (3.3V) to one relay contact and back from the other contact to a GPIO pin.

Alternatively check out [AC main detector module](https://www.electroschematics.com/detector-module/) for schematics on how to do it with an optocoupler.

Comment: Thanks, the link was just what I was looking for, I already knew about the relay, but this wasn't a viable solution for costs and space. Anyway at the end i used the solution attached to the first post

Comment: Very thanks for the info. But I'm really new and I can't understand how to use a relay to get the input form a button. I know if I send a signal to relay this will open the circuit of 220v.
But I need, when the circuit of 220v is closed (now my button is 24v I think is the same with different relay), send a signal to esp32 (I use esphome to compile the esp32 device) The "AC main detector module" maybe is good, but I can't find a DC 24v version The thing I need is: when the 24v circuit is closed send a signal to esp32. Very thanks Niks